# selecting first 6 element with xpath [position() <= 6]

Tags: php, xpath

I am scraping some image datas from a website. No problem 'till here. But my way of usage is not working out.

My xpath query right below. Trying to use `position()` for selecting first 6 el. But it's still returning all elements.

```
  $route = $path->query("//li/img[@class='lazy'][position() <= 6]");
  foreach($route as $val){

      var_dump(trim($val->getAttribute("data-original")));

  }
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong here? Also is there other way to select first 6 elements apart from `position()`?

Comment: but your position() < 10, but you need 6 elements?

Comment: oh sorry for the typo. but in the end 6 or 10 i can't get the numbers of elements that written in the position @metal

Comment: can you share the xml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you need this.

```
  $route = $path->query("//li[1]/img[@class='lazy' and position() <= 6]");
  foreach($route as $val){

      var_dump(trim($val->getAttribute("data-original")));

  }
```

if you don't want to specify the index of your `<li>` you need to use a counter.

```
 $route = $path->query("//li/img[@class='lazy' and position() <= 6]");
 $ctr = 0;
      foreach($route as $val){
         if ($ctr <= 6){
          var_dump(trim($val->getAttribute("data-original")));
         }
         $ctr = $ctr + 1;
      }
```

Comment: thank you, but it still taking all elements... not just first 6

Comment: can you share the xml?

Comment: you mean url? here: https://zexy.net/wedding/c_7770025771/imageGallery/

Comment: updated the answer, you need to specify the first instance of your <li> node.

Comment: oh, I tried that before. But when I do that. it returns nothing, no error as well... in your version is it returns?

Comment: yes, this is working http://www.utilities-online.info/xpath/?save=8891d068-a09c-4f1b-92de-b906034ba0c1-xpath